# Перенос комментариев при объединении

Tags: дефект, статус-проверка, инструменты-модератора

При объединении вопросов
[Не работает сайт в IE 11 а в других браузерах работает [дубликат]](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/967470?noredirect=1)
[D3 не работает в internet Explorer 11](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/967500/178988)
не перенёсся комментарий автора вопроса.

Комментарии у исходного вопроса после объединения:

> [image: скриншот комментариев исходного вопроса]

Комментарии у целевого вопроса после объединения:

> [image: скриншот комментариев целевого вопроса]

Comment: А комментарии вообще должны объединяться?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, да, комментарии переносятся. Все остальные комментарии тоже под оригинальным вопросом были - они перенеслись, а авторский - нет.